# HTML CSS Make DIV as long as content not window

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a simple login form that allows the user to do a few different things.  Each of those things opens a "modal" window in the browser.  As long as the content of the login form doesn't extend off the screen, then everything is good.  When it does and the user scrolls down, then the modal portion only covers the size of the browser so the rest of the form is uncovered.  This allows them to open a second modal block.

My CSS for the modal block is:

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 40%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  padding: 16px;
}
```

My CSS for the opaque covering is:

```
.modalpwd {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  overflow: visible;
  align-self: center;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */  
}
```

My HTML for the modal portion is:

```
<div id="divResetPwd" class="modalpwd">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('divResetPwd').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h1>First Time Login - Set Password</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to set your password.</p>
        <hr/>

        <label for="psw"><b>Verification Code</b></label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" placeholder="Enter the verification code sent to your email address" id="txtCode2" >

        <label for="psw"><b>New Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter New Password" runat="server" id="txtpsw">

        <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat New Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat New Password" runat="server" id="txtpswrepeat">

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('divResetPwd').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" runat="server" id="btndivResetPwd" class="signupbtn" onserverclick="SetPassword">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Finally I have attached two pictures.  One shows the screen before scrolling and the second shows the screen after scrolling.  If the user clicks on the Sign Up button in the second picture, then a second "modal" window is displayed.

[image: Before Scrolling]
[image: After Scrolling]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anywhere we can see a working example of this?

Comment: @MonneratRJ Probably not a good idea. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use fixed positioning on the overlay instead of absolute positioning. Absolute position will scroll with the page, fixed positioning won't. You can learn more about the differences [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Here's your updated overlay code:

```css
.modalpwd {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  overflow: visible;
  align-self: center;  
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */  
}
```

Comment: his form is taller than the window tough... maybe if he makes it `overflow:scroll;` and resize the form for a smaller div, i dunno, it's missing info in this one...

Comment: @MonneratRJ The problem isn't the modal scrolling, it's the fact that the overlay doesn't cover the bottom of the page. I think the OP phrased the question a little weird. I could be wrong, thoguh

Comment: oh i can see what you mean now, if he just wants the modal background to cover the page behind it, your answer is correct... maybe i misunderstood the question